# Summative Pattern

Tags: combinatorics, j

While playing around with J ([link](http://www.tryj.tk/)), I found that you can create a sequence of shape `N0 N1 ... NK` with `i.` taking a list  as its parameters. Since `i.` creates a range `0 .. RHS` and `>:` increments each value in a range, `i. >: i. RHS` creates a non-empty range. We can use `,` to flatten it and `+/` to summate it. Given an RHS, this looks like:

```
+/ , i. >: i. RHS
```

One can trivially convert this to a tacit expression using an extended monadic fork and capping the left branch `[:`.

```
[: +/ [: , [: i. [: >: i.
```

However, I find this rather bulky and that it could be more concise. How might I make it more so?

I have found a more concise solution that I would also like feedback on. Observing that the last members in each of the lists (before being summated) is `(n-1)!`. Since `,` flattens the list, we can emulate this with `i.`, and since the endpoint is not included, we have another solution:

```
+/ i. ! RHS
```

Converting this to a tacit expression in the same way as above yields:

```
[: +/ [: i. !
```

However, I do not know of a better method for converting a monadic sequence of operations to a tacit verb.

Moving some verbs into variables:

```
sum =: +/
cap =: [:
cap sum cap i. !
```

How can this code be improved?

---

Some example input/outputs (work for both functions).

```
   sum =: +/
   cap =: [:
   sp =: cap sum cap i. !
   max =: 8
   (2 , max) $ (i.max) , (sp"0 i.max)
0 1 2  3   4    5      6        7
0 0 1 15 276 7140 258840 12698280
```

The first row is input to `sp`, and the second row is its output.

Comment: Have you tried using `@` instead of `[:`?

Comment: I found this sequence in [OEIS A180397](http://oeis.org/A180397). It is equivalent to C(_n_!, 2) for _n_ ≥ 2.

Comment: @200_success Oh! How interesting!

Comment: Hey Connor, commenting bc I don't have an _answer_ for you, but I've asked this question on J irc a few times, and I think the short answer is (but don't quote me for _certain_): there isn't a better way.  You're stuck with `[:` or `@` (which usually requires parens) -- neither ideal.  It's frustrating because the non-tacit right to left eval gives you a beautiful succinct pipeline by default:  `+/ , i. >: i. 4` equals `([: +/ [: , [: i. [: >: i.) 4`, the former being much prettier obv.  What one wants is to say "save this as a tacit verb, but then execute it _as if_ not tacit".  Alas....

Answer (score 3):

You're likely aware of this already, but just for posterity it's worth noting that you can always create an anonymous verb:

```
(3 :'+/ , i. >: i.y') 6
```

The extra 5 (or 7, if you count the parens, which are often optional) characters you spend pay for themselves after about 3 fork caps...